# Save the data in the Postgresql database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, web-scraping

I don't catch how to save the scraped data in the Postgresql database.
I tried to use Psycopg2 without effect...
I learned that I can use django models for this

The scraper should scrape every blog post on each page Data from the scraper should go to the Postgresql database, where the following statistics will be counted:

1.The 10 most common words along with their numbers under the address /stats

2.The 10 most common words with their numbers per author available under the address / stats / /

3. posts authors with their name available in the address / stats / / available under the address / authors /

in the code below, for example, I tried to get the names of the authors but I get such an error :

```
authors = Author(name='author name')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

importing models to the scraper does not help either...

Here is my scraper:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from collections import Counter


url = 'https://teonite.com/blog/page/{}/index.html'
all_links = []


headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('https://teonite.com/blog/')
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    article_links = ['https://teonite.com' + item['href'][2:] for item in soup.select('.post-content a')]
    all_links.append(article_links)
    num_pages = int(soup.select_one('.page-number').text.split('/')[1])


    for page in range(2, num_pages + 1):
        r = s.get(url.format(page))
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        article_links = ['https://teonite.com' + item['href'][2:] for item in soup.select('.post-content a')]
        all_links.append(article_links)



    all_links = [item for i in all_links for item in i]

    d = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

    contents = []
    authors = []

    for article in all_links:
        d.get(article)
        soup = bs(d.page_source, 'lxml')
        [t.extract() for t in soup(['style', 'script', '[document]', 'head', 'title'])]
        visible_text = soup.getText()
        content = soup.find('section', attrs={'class': 'post-content'})
        contents.append(content)
        Author = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'author-content'})
        authors.append(Author)

##  Below is the two lines of code where is the error

        authors = Author(name='author name')
        Author.save()

        unique_authors = list(set(authors))
        unique_contents = list(set(contents))
        try:
            print(soup.select_one('.post-title').text)
        except:
            print(article)
            print(soup.select_one('h1').text)
            break  # for debugging
    d.quit()
```

Models:

```
from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model):
    author_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50, editable=False)
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-author_id']
        db_table = 'author'


class Stats(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    stats = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-stats']
        db_table = 'stats'



class AuthorStats(models.Model):
    author_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    stats = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['stats']
        db_table = 'author_stats'
```

Answer (score 0):

You've eplicitly set `Author` to be something other than the model:

```
Author = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'author-content'})
```

Import the model `Author`, and don't hide it.

(And you're doing something similar with `authors`.)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Author` in a wrong way. You need to:

1. Import your models.py
2. You don't need the local `authors` list.
3. Change `Author = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'author-content'})` to something like `author_raw = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'author-content'})`.
4. Create author by `author = models.Author(name=author_raw.name)` and save it by `author.save()`. (I don't know what `soap.find` returns for authors so you can edit that part in your `Author` model constructor parameters.)